# Add a item / page in the portlet admin menu in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I want to add an other item in the admin menu in a portlet.
For example, add an item "Organization" between Apparence and Configuration.
Is it possible ??

[image: screenshot of portlet menu]

However, i tested a new configuration page in the Configuration menu.

So i add in portlet.xml :

```
<init-param> 
    <name>config-jsp</name> 
    <value>/html/foo/configuration.jsp</value> 
</init-param>
```

in liferay-portlet.xml :

```
<configuration-action-class>com.projecto.ec.config.ConfigurationActionFooImpl</configuration-action-class>
```

and my ConfigurationActionPrenalyticImpl looks like this :

```
public class ConfigurationActionPrenalyticImpl implements ConfigurationAction {

    @Override
    public void processAction(PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String render(PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {
        return "/html/preanalytic/configuration.jsp";
    }

}
```

But i don't know how to init correctly this page with some content like in a doView or doEdit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it is possible, but is none of the standard extension paths that you typically would go within Liferay. A standard way would be to either implement the JSR-286 "edit" mode or contribute another configuration page to the Liferay-specific configuration.

I've never seen the extension you're intending to do in the wild, and I'm assuming that it would require some poking in the internals. It's most likely not well documented. Given that 6.x is the last release that does not use OSGi (and everything will change with Liferay 7 / DXP), I'm not sure if I should recommend going this way.